# What is the best way to group series of dates in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

From the series of dates,

```
arr = ["2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08",
       "2020-01-09", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14"]
```

How can we group them such as the output becomes as following:

```
["Jan 5th - Jan 9th", "Feb 12th - Feb 14th"]
```

The dates that fall within the range should be grouped as above. The year is known to be the same for all elements of `arr` and therefore can be disregarded.

Comment: Are you ignoring the year?

Comment: Why `Jan 5th - Jan 9th`? Why not `Jan 3rd - Jan 7th`? What about the dates like `Jan 10th?`

Comment: Code, I trust that my edit is consistent with the question you want answered.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say you can convert them with `to_date`, group them by their `month` and map them by their `minmax`:

```
arr
  .map(&:to_date)
  .group_by(&:month)
  .map do |_, dates|
    dates.minmax.map { |date| date.to_s(:long_ordinal) }.join(' - ')
  end
# ["January 5th, 2020 - January 9th, 2020", "February 12th, 2020 - February 14th, 2020"]
```

The `to_s(:long_ordinal)` is to get a formatted string.

Comment: Shorter than my answer below. Nice one!

Comment: I think `arr.map(&:to_date).chunk_while { |a, b| a == b.prev_day }` would resemble the problem more closely. (grouping consecutive days instead of finding the min/max day of each month)

Comment: @Stefan That's a nice find, but should probably be it's own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ["2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14"]
arr
  .map { |d| Date.parse(d) }
  .group_by { |d| d.month }
  .sort
  .map do |d| 
    dt = d.last
    min = dt.min
    max = dt.max

    "#{min.strftime('%b')} #{min.day.ordinalize} - #{max.strftime('%b')} #{dt.max.day.ordinalize}"
   end
```

Comment: You could use `minmax` and destructure. Also for `dt` (`|_, dt| `).

Answer (score 1):

You could do that as follows.

```
require 'date'

ORDINAL = { 1=>"st", 2=>"nd", 3=>"rd" }.tap { |h| h.default = "th" } 

arr.group_by { |s| s[5,2] }.
    map do |mon, arr|
      mon_name = Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[mon.to_i]
      first_day, last_day = arr.map { |s| s[-2,2].to_i }.minmax.
        map { |d| "%d%s" % [d, ORDINAL[d%10]] }
      "%s %s - % s %s" % [mon_name, first_day, mon_name, last_day]
    end
  #=> ["Jan 5th - Jan 9th", "Feb 12nd - Feb 14th"]
```

The steps are as follows:

```
ORDINAL = { 1=>"st", 2=>"nd", 3=>"rd" }.tap { |h| h.default = "th" }
```

```
ORDINAL[0] #=> "th" 
ORDINAL[1] #=> "st" 
ORDINAL[2] #=> "nd" 
ORDINAL[3] #=> "rd" 
ORDINAL[4] #=> "th"
...
```

```
h = arr.group_by { |s| s[5,2] }
  #=> {"01"=>["2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07",
  #           "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09"],
  #    "02"=>["2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14"]} 
enum = h.to_a.each
  #=> #<Enumerator:...
mon, arr = enum.next
  #=> ["01", ["2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07",
  #           "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09"]] 
mon
  #=> "01" 
arr
  #=> ["2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08",
  #    "2020-01-09"] 
mon_name = Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[mon.to_i]
  #=> "Jan" 
a = arr.map { |s| s[-2,2].to_i }
  #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
b = a.minmax
  #=> [5, 9] 
first_day, last_day = b.map { |d| "%d%s" % [d, ORDINAL[d%10]] }
  #=> ["5th", "9th"] 
"%s %s - % s %s" % [mon_name, first_day, mon_name, last_day]
  #=> "Jan 5th - Jan 9th"
```

```
mon, arr = enum.next
  #=> ["02", ["2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14"]]
```

The remaining steps are similar.

Answer (score 0):

No other answer handles single days and multiple runs of consecutive days in the same month:

```rb
dates = ["2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07",
         "2020-01-09",
         "2020-01-12", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-14",
         "2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14"].map(&Date.method(:parse))

def ordinalize(num)
  ordinals = { 1 => :st, 2 => :nd, 3 => :rd, 4 => :th }
  ord_num = (11..13).cover?(num.abs % 100) ? 4 : num.abs
  "#{num}#{ordinals[ord_num]}"
end

grouped = dates.sort.chunk_while { |a, b| a + 1 == b }.map(&:minmax).map(&:uniq)
grouped.map do |group|
  group.map { |date| date.strftime("%b #{ordinalize(date.day)}") }.join(" - ")
end

# => ["Jan 5th - Jan 7th", "Jan 9th", "Jan 12th - Jan 14th", "Feb 12th - Feb 14th"]
```

mini-bonus, happens to have no dependencies on `ActiveSupport`

Comment: So you got Rails, but you don't use Rails, very cool. The question is Rails tagged.

Comment: Are you taking personal offense to not using Rails or something? You can use Rails if you want, it's trivial to swap out `ordinalize`. I've just created an example that is self-sufficient, what's wrong with that?